# Can we return reference of local const variable C++

Tags: c++, reference, constants, local

since const variables are stored in read only memory. Can we return reference of
const variable form function ?

Please suggest the answer.

```
int& fun()
{
    int a = 10;
    const int b = a;
    return b;
}
```

Also please help me with memory lay out of C++ program where does const values are stored. Where read only data are present ?

Answer (score 3):

"since const variables are stored in read only memory" - that is not correct. And the nswer is "no", you cannot safely return a reference to a local varible - `const` or not. The variable is destroyed when you return from the function and the reference is then no longer valid.

Comment: Well, you can certainly return the reference. That's perfectly valid. What's not valid is using the referenced object.

Answer (score 1):

`Const` only means non-modifiable; it doesn't always mean "known at compile time". For instance, this is a const variable whose value is not known at compile time:

```
void fun(int x)
{
    const int b = x;
}
```

Where the variable lives (and how long it lives) is defined by its *storage duration*, and `const` is not a storage duration. The possible storage durations are:

- "full-expression": the object exists until the end of the statement. In `int foo = int(4) + int(5)`, `int(4)` and `int(5)` both have full-expression storage duration. On all implementations that I know, these live on the stack.
- automatic: local variables and struct fields and such. Their lifetime is the same as that of their parent scope. (Notably, local variables–even `const`–only live as long as their function execute.)
- `thread_local`: only possible on global variables; each thread views a unique version of it. They are dynamically allocated at once when the thread begins and freed when it terminate.
- `static`: available throughout the entire lifetime of the program (global variables). These are stored in memory regions that are mounted by the operating system when the program starts. These regions are distinct from those that we usually call the "stack" and the "heap".
- "dynamic": memory allocations obtained by `new` and such. Lives on the heap.

On most platform, `const` is "truly const" (will crash your program if you attempt to modify it) only when applied to a variable of static storage duration. Regardless, it is undefined behavior to modify a variable that was initially declared `const`, whatever was its storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

Storage classes of a variable defines existence of variable in program during execution. In your example scope of variable is only with in function and storage class type of auto. Any reference to variable outside the scope of function will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the variable as a reference, then please make the variable has "static" , since it is stored globally.